# How to use YQL in JavaScript to retrieve web results

Tags: javascript, html, json, yql

I have been trying the code given in 
[How to use YQL to retrieve web results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176668/how-to-use-yql-to-retrieve-web-results)

but it is not working.

Please suggest me something else or rectify that code.

I am just calling a function on page_load

```
<body onload = "load_content();">
```

In the load_content() method, I have to get the feed of other web site and display it on my HTML page.

**Load_Content method**

```
     var query = "select * from html where url='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123865/'";

    // Define your callback:
    var callback = function(data) {
    console.log("DATA : " + data);
    };

    // Instantiate with the query:
    var firstFeedItem = new YQLQuery(query, callback);

    // If you're ready then go:
    console.log("FEED : " + firstFeedItem.fetch()); // Go!!
```

**Function YQLQuery**

```
    function YQLQuery(query, callback) 
    {
        this.query = query;
        this.callback = callback || function(){};
        this.fetch = function() {

        if (!this.query || !this.callback) {
            throw new Error('YQLQuery.fetch(): Parameters may be undefined');
        }

        var scriptEl = document.createElement('script'),
            uid = 'yql' + +new Date(),
            encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(this.query.toLowerCase()),
            instance = this;

        YQLQuery[uid] = function(json) {
            instance.callback(json);
            delete YQLQuery[uid];
            document.body.removeChild(scriptEl);
        };

        scriptEl.src = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='
                     + encodedQuery + '&format=json&callback=YQLQuery.' + uid; 
        document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);

    };
  }
```

Nothing is coming in data variable

Comment: Please show your `load_content()` function code.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: callback function is not getting any data.
console is just showing undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple get request is an answer to this.

```
 $.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1243957/",
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }//end function(data)
 );//end getJSON
```